# Correctness of a set with respect to another set.

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

Is there a specific measure for correctness of a Set w.r.t another set?
e.g. Consider there's a base set A, and a set B whose correctness needs to be measured w.r.t set A. Now B might contain some additional elements w.r.t A, and/or might be missing a few elements. Is there a well defined and widely accepted measure for correctness of set B w.r.t set A?

Comment: What does "correctness" mean?

Comment: Well, that's technically my question if there  is a notion/measure of correctness. Consider set A to be the 'correct' set. So, the required measure needs to define how much of set B is correct i.e. its match with set A. 
note: I am not looking for Jaccard Similarity as an answer. :)

Comment: I assume you are talking about finite sets?

Comment: Yes, finite sets.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a space $S$, and sets $A, B \subseteq S$, and you would like to measure some notion of how similar $B$ matches $A$ in terms of its elements.  I don't think there is a universally accepted answer to that, simply because different applications want to emphasize different aspects of similarity.  One *common* notion is that of overlap: $\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}$.  But that is only one possible notion, and other ones may have different emphases on "false positives" versus "false negatives".

Answer (score 0):

So $B$ is *supposed* to contain just the elements of $A$. $A, B \subset S$.

Let $FP$ (for false positives) $= |B \setminus A|$.

Let $FN$ (for false negatives) $= |A \setminus B|$.

Let $TP = |A \cap B|$.

Let $TN = |(S \setminus A) \cap (S \setminus B)|$

Then a measure might be $TP \times v_{TP} + TN \times v_{TN} - FN \times c_{FN} - FP \times c_{FP}$ where $v_{TP}$ is value of true positive and $c_{FN}$ is cost of false negative.